# Powershell sql provider databases collection missing system databases

Tags: database, powershell, system, provider

When connecting to the powershell sql provider on 2008R2 the Databases collection does not seem to include the system databases.
Any ideas how to include master, msdb, etc. in the returned list ? 
Using SMO does it, I was just curious how to do it with the provider.

E.g

```
push-location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$env:COMPUTERNAME\DEFAULT\Databases" 
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name 
Pop-Location
```

Returns:

```
Name    
----
DBA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way:

```
push-location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$env:COMPUTERNAME\DEFAULT\Databases" 
Get-ChildItem -force | Select-Object Name 
Pop-Location
```